# SSIS export to CSV file failing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to export the contents of a SQL Server 2005 table to a csv file using SSIS. In the Data Flow Task I have a OLE DB Source for the table and a Flat File Destination for the file.

When copying the data I started getting a failure on one of the column on a certain row and following some investigation found the problem was with comma's in the data below

**Data Issue (nvarchar255)**

```
errors code l075 showing,,,re test.
```

**OLE DB Source for Comment col**

[image]

**Derived Column**

Given that this was the issue I created a Derived Column object between the source and destination and destination objects and tried filtering out the comma's using a replace `REPLACE(Comment,","," ")` but the same column is still failing with the below errors.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Destination Component**

[image]

**Exception**

[image]

[Inspection Failures  Destination [206]] Error: Data conversion failed. 
The data conversion for column "Comment" returned status value 4 and 
status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no 
match in the target code page.".

[Inspection Failures  Destination [206]] Error: Cannot copy 
or convert flat file data for column "Comment".

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.
The ProcessInput method on component "Inspection Failures
Destination" (206) failed with error code 0xC02020A0 while 
processing input "Flat File Destination Input" (207). The 
identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput 
method. The error is specific to the component, but the error
 is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.
There may be error messages posted before this with more 
information about the failure.

[Inspecton Failures Source [128]] Error: The attempt to 
add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error 
code 0xC0047020.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.
The PrimeOutput method on component "Inspecton Failures Source"
 (128) returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned 
a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). 
The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, 
but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
There may be error messages posted before this with more 
information about the failure.

Comment: Usually this error is when column: data type and lenght don't match in two elements: derived column and source element. Try this(without space): `REPLACE(Comment,",","")` or this `SUBSTRING(REPLACE(Comment,",",""),1,255)`

Comment: I tried both and its still failing on the same row and column

Comment: Oh this about destination error??  So where you are writing the column element is to short or data type dont match. Yeah they both are red, because Destination can't write and source don't now what to do... Show **Destination** advanced `Input Columns` the column where you writing comment

Comment: Just uploaded destination image. As far as I can see the datatype (DT_WSTR) and Length (255) are correct

Comment: Yes you right. Hm could be error because of memory or you inserting strings with commas  in   text file delimeted by commas....

Comment: I have changed the source query to only bring through the one problem row and it fails so I don't think its a memory issue. I think it is to do with the multiple comma's in the Comment column but don't understand why the Replace is not removing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem actually appears to be a hidden illegal character in the text

In the image below the top line shows a square before the `re test` string. The comment column in the database is an nvarchar which apparently uses a different character set so I can not just use the CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) to replace the carriage return.

The fix involved converting the field from an nvarchar to a varchar then performing a replace on the converter ? character resulting in the corrected second ling in the image

```
SELECT ID,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(Comment AS varchar(255)),'?',' '),',',' ') Comment
FROM tblInspectionFailures  WHERE (ID = 216899)
```

[image]

[The conversion requirement is detailed here](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/84141-using-replace-nchar-stored-procedure)

This does not should like an ideal solution to me but it does work. Does anyone have any other options.

Comment: Wow, it looks like line break. There probably isn't better solution, unless before writing to table you can Delete illegal characters with programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Without replacing comment column can you create another column and map the new derived column to destination column and see.

Comment: Instead of creating a derived column for comment column(REPLACE(Comment,","," ")) Can you fetch directly from SQL Server 2005. Check the query if it is running fine in Management Studio.

Comment: you mean to say the query works fine in management studio and while inserting data it fails or its not working in management studio.

Comment: yes. I think I may have found another issue. When pasting the comment field it looks like this (square before the re test) 'errors code l075 showing,,,re test.' I think the application may have entered a carriage return. I'm trying to string it out with 'replace ( replace(Comment, char(10),''), char(13), '')' bit so far its not working